# Push down of a regular function on the blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $\hat X$ the blow-up of $X$ at a point $p$.

Assuming $\hat f$ is a regular function on $\hat X$ vanishing on the exceptional divisor, can we prove that the push-down of $f$ on $X$ is also regular?

Comment: In your situation any regular function on the blow up is the pull back from $X$ of a regular function.

Comment: @Mohan Can you explain why the statement is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be the pushdown function of $\hat f$. Then it is clear from the definition of the blow-up that $f$ is regular on $X-\{p\}$. In particular, $f$ is a rational function on $X$. In fact, $f$ is also regular at $p$ since otherwise $\text{div}_{\infty}(f)$ is a point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be the exceptional divisor. If $\dim X=1$, $\hat{X}=X$ and so nothing to prove, so assume that $\dim X\geq 2$. If $f$ is a regular function on $\hat{X}$ it gives a regular function on $\hat{X}-E=X-\{p\}$. Any regular function on $X-\{p\}$ extends to a regular function $g$ on $X$. Now pull back of $g$ and $f$ agree on the dense open set $\hat{X}-E$ and hence must be equal.

Comment: Could you explain why "Any regular function on $X-\{p\}$ extends to a regular function $g$ on $X$" holds?

Comment: @zhiqiang Look up Hartog's theorem.